# how to take a value less than 0 if recorded obtained like this?

Tags: mysql, sql

My Query:

```
 select c.location_id as id_gudang, c.location_name as nama_gudang, a.item_code as id_barang, a.item_name as nama_barang, sum(b.item_qty) as qty
    from t_inventory as a
    join t_inventory_transaction as b on a.item_id = b.item_id
    join t_site_location as c on b.whse_id = c.location_id
    group by a.item_code
```

This data from query

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Sample data with expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want records with `qty` < 0?

Comment: yes, iam want qty < 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that, you can wrap your sql into a subquery like:

```
select *
from (
    select c.location_id as id_gudang, c.location_name as nama_gudang, a.item_code as id_barang, a.item_name as nama_barang, sum(b.item_qty) as qty
    from t_inventory as a
    join t_inventory_transaction as b on a.item_id = b.item_id
    join t_site_location as c on b.whse_id = c.location_id
    group by a.item_code) t
where qty < 0
```

Or just use `HAVING`:

```
select c.location_id as id_gudang, c.location_name as nama_gudang, a.item_code as id_barang, a.item_name as nama_barang, sum(b.item_qty) as qty
from t_inventory as a
join t_inventory_transaction as b on a.item_id = b.item_id
join t_site_location as c on b.whse_id = c.location_id
group by a.item_code
having qty < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you say you want `qty < 0` that you want `null` values (those that don't exist in that table), then you need to be using an `outer join` instead:

```
select c.location_id as id_gudang, c.location_name as nama_gudang, 
       a.item_code as id_barang, a.item_name as nama_barang, 
       sum(b.item_qty) as qty
from t_inventory as a
    left join t_inventory_transaction as b on a.item_id = b.item_id
    left join t_site_location as c on b.whse_id = c.location_id
group by a.item_code
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

This returns all records from the `t_inventory` table regardless if they don't exist in the other tables.